# How can I display an image whose path is outside my Ruby on Rails project directory using rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, html-helper

how to display the image, which stored outside from the project directory?

Is there a simple way to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I see two ways :

- On top of your rails server, in production and sometimes in dev, you have to use a web server like apache or nginx. With these, you can serve files from other directories for specific URL. E.G. you can make `http://yourapp.com/images/` serving files from a specific dir. In rails, display the image with a traditionnal `image_tag`

Example with Nginx :

```
    # Find the right `server` section which you currently use to serve your rails app
server {
      listen 80;

      # Add this
      location /images {
        root /var/www/my/specific/folder;
      }

      location / {
        #...
        #... Here you should already some code to proxy to your rails server
      }
    }

With that, when you access to `yourserver.com/images`, nginx serve your specific folder and not your rails app. Then in your app view :

    <%= image_tag 'http://yourserver.com/images/my_pic.jpg' %>
```

- If you can't access your server settings, you can serve an image file from a controller action with `send_file`

  In a controller :

  ```
  class ImagesController < ApplicationController
    def show
      send_file File.join('/var/www/my/specific/folder',params[:name]), :disposition => 'inline'
    end
  end
  ```

  In `config/routes.rb`

  ```
  match '/images/:name' => 'images#show', :as => :custom_image
  ```

  Then when you access this action (via the route you defined in `config/routes.rb`), you have the image. So in your view you do a traditionnal `image_tag` with this URL :

  ```
  <%= image_tag custom_image_path( 'my_pic.jpg' ) %>
  OR
  <%= image_tag custom_image_url( 'my_pic.jpg' ) %>
  ```

Comment: See my edit. I show you how to use it with a custom named route.

Comment: AFAIK, no. Within the rails scope, you have to follow the rails stack.  But a controller is created in circa 30s... You can integrate the action inside an other controller if you want. I'd rather recommend you to see for the first solution : even if now in dev you don't have a web server on top of your app, in production you will, so you'd better spend your time in learn how to configure it (make a virtualhost on apache or a new server in nginx...)

Comment: I tried the first one, using nginx server but it was unable to load the url given.

Answer (score 0):

If it's stored outside of the Rails app directory, then it does not belong to asset pipeline and you can simply link to it:

```
<%= image_tag("http://example.com/some_file.jpg") %>
```

Obviously it must be accessible through HTTP (you need nginx or Apache server installed).

Comment: How are you using your application in production then? Are you just running Mongrel on port 80?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably bad idea and will lead to a bunch of issues.  Some security, some functionality, but most of the effects I actually don't know.
I do know, from experience, that whenever you go against the rails **conventions** for what and where stuff is, it's a slippery slope of things breaking, best avoided.

Create a solution using the framework provided.

Note this functionality can also be affected a bit if you are using rails 3.1+ as opposed to <= 3.0 due to asset compilation which copies js, css and images into public.